# Need to ping a Device by Hostname on my network

Tags: ping, hostname

How do I ping by hostname? I have an Audio Video control system attached to our corporate network. All devices are set to DHCP including my laptop running Win7. All in the same subnet. I can ping all device by IP address but not hostname. 
Is this possible if there are no DNS entries on the devices? Some have a DNS entry and some do not.

Comment: You need a local DNS server in your network.  When I use a Westell ADSL modem/router, I can ping by hostname in both Windows and Linux PCs.  When I replace it with a Netgear modem/router, I lose that capability.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the device implements NetBIOS (or alike), then having a DNS entry will be necessary for resolution by host name.

If you are running a Windows domain, with a Windows DC that's both DHCP and the DNS for the domain, then you can pretty easily configure DHCP to dynamically update DNS when leases are given out.

So in that case, if the AV control device reports it's hostname to DHCP, then it'll be used to populate DNS automatically.